# Android SDK install specific component from commandline

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to install the Android 2.3.3 sdk component (prefs the Google API version) from the commandline on a remote amazon ec2 instance I have user access to, but not root access. Here is the command I'm using to simulate the install:

```
./android update sdk -u -n -t platform
```

Unfortunately, this wants to install just about every sdk component out there, starting at Android 1.5. Since this is a friend's machine, I don't want to use up his allocated bandwidth etc, and just want to get the sdk component I need. Is there a way I can modify the above command to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found answer. Will post it once stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://bugsnpieces.blogspot.com/2011/10/installing-specific-android-sdk.html